# How to show the value of specific key from nested array?

Tags: metabox, php

Before asking let me tell two things...
1)I know this is very east to someone, but it is hard to me.
2)I am facing this problem to create a WordPress template.That's why I have posted here.
Problem:
When I print_r the following codes then

```
<?php 

          $home_starting_player_names = rwmb_meta( 'pb_home_starting_player_options', array( 'multiple' => true ) ); ?>

          <?php 
           foreach ( $home_starting_player_names as $home_starting_player ){?>
            <li role="presentation">
            <aside class="starting-player-image"><?php  echo get_the_post_thumbnail($home_starting_player); ?></aside>
            <aside class="starting-player-name"><?php  echo get_the_title($home_starting_player); ?></aside>
           <aside class="starting-player-number"><?php $var_dumps = get_post_meta($home_starting_player); 

           print_r ($var_dumps);

           ?></aside>
       <?php } 
        ?>
```

it outputs as  follows (I have written only one here):

```
Array ( 
[_edit_last] => Array ( [0] => 1 )
 [_edit_lock] => Array ( [0] => 1477596212:1 )
 [pb_squad_number] => Array ( [0] => 10 ) 
[pb_player_date_birth] => Array ( [0] => 2016-09-02 )
)
```

Now I want to show the value of this key `[pb_squad_number]`.I mean 10.
Please help me through codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the key you want in `get_post_meta`:

```
echo get_post_meta( $home_starting_player, 'pb_squad_number', true );
```

WordPress loads all meta for any single meta call, so calling `get_post_meta` multiple times doesn't introduce any extra overhead.

Comment: Could you please answer this question:http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/242461/why-isnt-combined-meta-query-working

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this? : `var_dump($var_dumps[pb_squad_number][0]);`

Comment: You are also right but 2@Milo's answer  works more efficiently for me.Thanks